# How do I fix reference to register is pointing to the wrong one?

Tags: c, stm32

I'm trying to use the ADC in STM32 and I want to modify the ISR register so I'm doing `ADC->ISR |= <bit>`. However when I control-click on `ISR` it's bringing me to in `stm32f0xx/cmsis_boot/core_cm0.h`

```
/** \brief  Union type to access the Interrupt Program Status Register (IPSR).
 */
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    uint32_t ISR:9;                      /*!< bit:  0.. 8  Exception number                   */
    uint32_t _reserved0:23;              /*!< bit:  9..31  Reserved                           */
  } b;                                   /*!< Structure used for bit  access                  */
  uint32_t w;                            /*!< Type      used for word access                  */
} IPSR_Type;
```

I want to be brought to in `stm32f0xx/cmsis_boot/stm32f0xx.h`:

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t ISR;          /*!< ADC Interrupt and Status register, Address offset:0x00 */
  // other registers here                               
} ADC_TypeDef;
```

In my file, I'm not including either of those files so I'm not sure how the linking works. If I try to reference another register in `ADC_TypeDef` it works but I think because there are 2 `ISR` it can't find the right one. How do I fix this so that it's referencing the right one? Thanks!

Comment: `it's bringing me` What is the think that is bringing you? What IDE are you using?

Comment: @KamilCuk When I control click on ISR it's bringing me to that file so I'm assuming it's using that definition of ISR instead of the one I want. I'm using VS code

Comment: read your indexer documentation. It is not a programming question DV  & vote close